# Why particles are not rendering in Eevee engine even using the instancing object in Render option?

Tags: rendering, particles

So, I've made an animation of a drillbit cutting through a concrete wall, and I want to animate the chipset (dust) so I've used the vertex groups to make the particles system to emit from the head of the drill bit, I've assigned it to the vertex group which is named 'Group', applied rotation to the particles and using *Particle System> Render As Object* an Icosphere to render as the particles emit, the Icosphere has a concrete procedural material as well .

But nothing appears, if use the render mode at 'Halo', renders in the viewport but doesn't appear on the AVI output (viewport render animation).

I use viewport from render because I don´t have a great GPU, and use 16 samples as well. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Maybe the *Render > Scale* value of 0.050 is too small and the particles are so tiny that you can't see them?